# different result when running command indirectly though script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, pylint

i am using [`pylint`](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint) under virtual environment.

when running pylint directly, i get the following output

```sh
$ pylint src/**/*.py
************* Module main
src/main.py:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)
src/main.py:3:0: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 5.00/10 (previous run: 5.00/10, +0.00)
```

when the same command is wrapped in a bash script, executing the bash script yields a different output

```sh
$ $SHELL --version | head -n 1
GNU bash, version 5.0.18(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0)

$ which $SHELL
/usr/local/bin/bash

$ cat lint.sh
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
pylint *.py src/**/*.py

$ ./lint.sh
************* Module src/**/*.py
src/**/*.py:1:0: F0001: No module named src/**/*.py (fatal)

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
```

where the `lint.sh` and `src` directory are within the same (root) directory, the `src/**/*.py` within the `lint.sh` is correct.

here is more information about the execution environment

```sh
$ pylint --version
pylint 2.6.0
astroid 2.4.2
Python 3.8.5 (default, Aug  9 2020, 16:57:39)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.26.2)]
```

1. why running the command directly produces different output than running the same command indirectly (within a bash script, my assumption is that it has nothing to do with pylint directly)?
2. how can it be fixed to be able to run the command within a bash script?

Comment: I would expect it's because your virtual env is different to your current environment. If you set `source ~/.bash_profile` at the top does it still behave the same? Also your paths will be relative to your location. Again your pyenv might have a cd <dir> in it somewhere.

Comment: @bobdylan: so basically, all i need to do is add `-l` to the shabang. yet, when removing the shabang and there is no bash sub-shell, so why it acts like it?

Comment: Because you're not telling it what interpreter to use explicitly so it's behaving differently to your assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `**` in your script. This feature needs to be activated:

```
shopt -s globstar
pylint *.py src/**/*.py
```

Likely, it is enabled in your interactive shell, and that's why it works there. You can query its setting by doing a

```
shopt globstar
```